# SQL to DQ, use sub select

Tags: symfony, dql

I'm trying to convert a SQL function to a DQL function.

I don't know how to do the following step:

- Join on multiple class
- Join on temporary table (created by doctrine)
- Call a sub select in my function

Here my actual working SQL code.

```
SELECT ut.token
FROM user_token ut
INNER JOIN factory f ON f.id = ut.factory_id
INNER JOIN article_factory af ON af.factory_id = f.id
INNER JOIN article a ON a.id = af.article_id
WHERE ut.factory_id = (
    SELECT f.id
    FROM factory f
    INNER JOIN article_factory af ON af.factory_id = f.id
    INNER JOIN article a ON a.id = af.article_id
    WHERE a.id = :article
)
GROUP BY ut.token
```

In case of, here a screen of my table relation.

*article_factory* is not an entity or a class. *article_factory* was created for my relation between article and factory, when I specified a ManyToMany relation.

EDIT: Tryed throught plain SQL, but got issue making link between article and fatory, since DQL only know entity, and Doctrine is creating a table, which I canno't use. With DQL, I still got the same issue than above, I don't know how to properly join my classes, and make my sub-select.

[image: Table relations]

Comment: DQL use entity name, can you post your entity so we can build the query with DQL plz?! I might be already away by the time you do it, but it will help someone else answer your question. Else I will do it once I'm back... ;)

Comment: @Preciel edited the question with current entities. Tell me if you need anything, or if I missed something.

Comment: oh, I meant the entity files (userToken.php, factory.php, articleFactory.php, article.php), to get PHP variable names... I answered a similar question the other day, you can find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293878/make-an-iterable-array-of-objects-in-php-for-twig). I have to go for now, but if still unanswered, I will post a full answer

Comment: All variable are in the schema (took less place than all entities). That's why I said that user_token and article_factory wasn't entity, and only managed bu doctrine

Comment: @Preciel tryed with proper Entity name in plain SQL, but still got an issue on the middle-table (article_factory). And I don't know how to do with DQL, as I explain in the first post (Edit part).
I checked the link you posted above, it doesn't really help me about my issue, maybe I don't get it like I should.